# Регистронезависимый switch

Tags: c#, switch, рефакторинг

Есть у меня фрагмент кода в котором я хочу заменить if на switch:

```
if( request.SomeParam.Equals("Something1", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Execute1();
}

if (request.SomeParam.Equals("Something2", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Execute2();
}

throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(Request.Param));
```

Однако параметры регистронезависимые и придётся в case вписывать строки приведённые к нижнему регистру, что приведёт к понижению читаемости, т.к. в реальности "Something1" это достаточно длинная строка SomethingAndSomething и её визуально проще видеть именно так, а не искать границы слов в somethingandsomething.

Я пока пришёл к варианту:

```
const string SomethingAndSomething = "SomethingAndSomething";
const string SomethingOrSomething = "SomethingOrSomething";

switch(request.SomeParam.ToLowerInvariant())
{
    case SomethingAndSomething.ToLowerInvariant():
        Execute1();
        break;

    case SomethingOrSomething.ToLowerInvariant():
        Execute2();
        break;

    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(Request.Param));
}
```

Но не очень нравится это повторяющаяся мантра `.ToLowerInvariant()`, может быть есть какие-то ещё более удачные варианты рефакторинга?

Версия C# 7.0, т.е. есть возможность использовать и новые фичи языка.

Comment: здесь наверное вместо switch лучше делать `Dictionary`, ему можно в конструктор компарер передать

Comment: а разве в case можно не константное выражение подставить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const string SomethingAndSomething = "somethingandsomething";
const string SomethingOrSomething = "somethingorsomething";

const string someParamToLower = request.SomeParam.ToLowerInvariant();

switch(someParamToLower)
{
    case SomethingAndSomething:
        Execute1();
        break;

    case SomethingOrSomething:
        Execute2();
        break;

    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(Request.Param));
}
```

так?

Comment: Вот тут `= "somethingandsomething";` всё осталось в нижнем регистре. Хотя можно вот так сделать: `string SomethingAndSomething = "SomethingAndSomething".ToLowerInvariant();`, читаемость сохранится, хотя и ценой потери константы.

Comment: Пожалуй, всё таки на этом варианте остановлюсь + корректировкой `string SomethingAndSomething = "SomethingAndSomething".ToLowerInvariant();`

Answer (score 2):

Вместо приведения каждого из вариантов к Lower ты можешь привести только проверяемую часть к ловер или к аппер.

А в кейс сразу передавать надписи нужного регистра. И в таком случае будет приведение только в switch-е а не в каждом из кейсов.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать pattern matching. Он доступен начиная с версии C# 7.0.

```
string someParam = "somethingorsomething";

switch (someParam)
{
    case var param
    when param.Equals("SomethingAndSomething", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase):
        Console.WriteLine("and");
        break;

    case var param
    when param.Equals("SomethingOrSomething", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase):
        Console.WriteLine("or");
        break;

    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("error");
}
```

Выглядит в данном конкретном случае весьма громоздко. Но в других случаях паттерн матчинг может оказаться намного компактнее других способов.

Comment: Пожалуй, всё-таки тут хуже читаемость чем в ответе Сергея Кононова (с моим дополнением)... но всё равно спасибо за вариант с паттерн матчингом, ещё не использую в реальных проектах, хоть посмотрел как выглядит.